# How do I embed a table view within a UIView similar to how it's done in iBooks for font selection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

[image]

I want to implement something similar to how iBooks embeds a UITableView inside of a UIView for font selection, but I'm not sure how. Could anyone explain how this effect could be achieved?

(Note: This is for the iPhone.)

Comment: What have you tried so far? There is no problem adding a `UITableView` as a subview of a normal `UIView` but you need to provide a `UITableViewController` or data source to make it working. This, however, should be standard procedure (dig up some tutorials on that). Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Do I need a data source if it's static?

Comment: Well, if you use a custom `UITableViewController` then this one acts as the data source for your `UITableView` and you just have to implement it accordingly. - If you move this "popup" to a separate nib file and design it via interface builder, you should be able to just add the data as you need it with static cells.

Comment: I'm doing it on the iPhone (that screenshot is just an example) so I'm designing it programatically. I'm having a UITableView as a class instance variable, but I'm confused with how to initiate it, present it, set its delegate and everything. Most tutorials seem to outline how to do it with a custom UITableViewController, when I want to add it to an existing UIViewController.

Comment: How do you want it presented? The picture you show is probably a UITableViewController as the content controller of a popover. You need to specify how you want it to appear on an iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a UIPopover controller. The SettingsViewController is just a normal ViewController with a tableview. Try something like this:

```
-(IBAction)settings:(id)sender {

if (_poController != nil && [_poController isPopoverVisible] == YES) {

if ([_poController.contentViewController isKindOfClass:[SettingViewController class]]) {

  return;
} else {

  [_poController dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
}
}

SettingViewController* vc = [[SettingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController= [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[navController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];

CGRect f = vc.view.frame;
f.size.height = 237.0f;
f.size.width = 350.0f;
vc.view.frame = f;
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
vc.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(350.0f, 237.0f);

if (_poController == nil) {
_poController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]   initWithContentViewController:navController];
}
_poController.contentViewController = navController;
vc.controller = _poController;

[_poController presentPopoverFromRect:_settings.frame 
                             inView:_buttonsView
           permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp 
                           animated:YES];
[vc release];
[navController release];
}
```

Comment: I really should have been more specific, but I'm doing it on an iPhone. That screenshot is just showing the effect I want.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its exactly what you want but you might be able to use this:

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/wepopover

Its available on iPhone. Cocoa controls is also a good source for lots for custom controls, I've used it in the past.